# Trying to git add -A with EGit inside eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit

How do I do the equivalent of: `git add -A` with EGit.  This is a fairly common operation for me when working with many different files and I am hoping there is a better solution to clicking on each file and then clicking the add button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the *Git Staging* view  to stage files and commit. You can open it using Ctrl+3 (or Command+3) and typing its name.

There you can select all files and stage them via drag and drop or the context menu. In the upcoming EGit 3.2, there will also be a tree view which can be found in the view menu (the triangle).

Another option is using Team > Add to Index from the context menu of a project.

Comment: Thank you, both of these solutions work great and save me a bit of time now on each commit compared to before.